# c# wpf, is xaml nested property/controls inheritance possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
    <Grid Name="mainSceneGrid"  Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF075035">
        <Grid Name="navigationGrid">
            ......
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Normally from the code behind we would directly call `navigationGrid.xxx` which is very simple and effective. However when we start to get alot of dependent and nested grids for example it would be awesome to instead be able to call a property like this:

```
mainSceneGrid.navigationGrid.xxx
```

So we get some form of structured code and easier intellisense to work with, is this possible with xaml?

Comment: Topic title does not match the question asked.
But I cannot say how to change it correctly, since my knowledge of English is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what the names of UI elements are.

For XAML, firstly, it is registering a name in the visual tree of elements using the `FrameworkElement.RegisterName (String, Object)` method and then searching in this tree using the `FrameworkElement.FindName (String)` method.
This is mainly used for bindings of type ElementName.
These names must be unique within the scope of the names.

Secondly, the x: Name Directive creates, in addition to the name in the visual tree, a field in the "* .g.i.cs" file.
This file is the XAML reflection generated by Studio Designer.
You can view it if you place the cursor on the call to the `InitializeComponent ()` method and press F12.
It automatically changes when you change the XAML code.
And when you reference the name of an element in Code Behind, you are not actually referring to the name in XAML, but to a field in that file.
And if you know even a little about Sharpe, then you understand that you cannot create fields with names like `name1.name2`.

As for your problem, its origins are that you are not working with WPF in a way that is typical for WPF.
WPF is designed around the concept of UI elements getting values ​​for their properties on their own through bindings.
Therefore, using WPF element names other than ElementName bindings is a sign of incorrect implementation.
Such incorrect implementation methods are fraught with the occurrence of specific tasks, code bloat, and a high probability of bugs and errors.

I advise you, especially at the initial stage of training, in general, do not even open the "* .xaml.cs" files.
There should be nothing in the Code Behind other than calling the `InitializeComponent ()` method.
When you learn the basics of WPF (layout, bindings, data context, styles, templates, triggers, converters), then you will be able to consciously decide on the use of Code Behind.
But in practice, there are almost no such tasks where it is really needed.